# Show SimpleDialogFragment message alert in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator, fragmentmanager

I have a Main activity that extends from FragmentActivity, like this:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public static CustomFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
...
//I can access to canAccessFromMain() in SecondTab like this:
((SecondTab)Main.mAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(1)).canAccessFromMain();
}
```

With two fragments, like this:

```
public class SecondTab extends Fragment implements ISimpleDialogListener{
...
//Access to objects in Main like this:
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)Main.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
...

@Override
public void onPositiveButtonCLicked(int requestedCode){
if(requestedCode == 12}{
//Do something //Problem is here, it's never called!
}
...

public void canAccessFromMain(){
mImageView.setVisibility(View.invisible);
}

private void DoSomething(){
//I test all of these, but not working:
//getActivity(),getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
//getActivity(),((SecondTab )Main.mAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(1))).getFragmentManager()
//Main.fragmentManager
SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(getActivity(),getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
.setTitle("ttt")
.setMessage("mmm")
.setPositiveButtonText("OK").setRequestCode(12)
.setNegativeButtonText("No")
.show();

...
}
```

And this is CustomFragmentAdapter class:

```
//liek this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager
class CustomFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
...
public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position){
return registeredFragments.get(posotion);
}
```

I'm using this library to show a alert message: https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Why when i press positive or negative button that show in secondtab fragment, nothings happed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call method `setTargetFragment()` in your builder.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: The library has own listener that i implemented from ISimpleDialogListener and Override its method onPositiveButtonCLicked.